# SQl - ORA993 Command Not properly Ended

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

The Code:

```
UPDATE
        bid
SET
        bid.salesman_id = s.salesman_id
FROM
        bid
INNER JOIN
        salesman
ON
        bid.salesman = s.display_name
WHERE 
        bid.salesman is not null
```

When i run it, it produces a ora 993 error - stating the sql statement was not properly ended.

bid and salesman are table names

Comment: One thing that jumps out is you are using `s` as a table alias, but have never aliased a table as `s`.

Comment: Have you looked at <http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00933_sql_command_ended.htm>?

Comment: sorry guys the s is supposed to be salesman

Comment: @jordan.peoples - 
right ">" got sucked into the URL 
Should be: ( http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00933_sql_command_ended.htm )

Comment: @PM77-1 , i havent seen that exact site... but yes, of course ive seen and read this exact issue before coming here.  it does not apply to my question/sql at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, that isn't valid in Oracle.

I think you'll have to try something like this:

```
UPDATE bid SET bid.salesman_id = (SELECT salesman.salesman_id
                                  FROM salesman
                                  WHERE bid.salesman = salesman.display_name)
WHERE bid.salesman is not null
```

Comment: awesome thanks, and thanks for figuring out that my s. meant salesman.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing I do not see where you are creating the alias for salesman s. You could also do:

```
Update bid
set bid.salesman_id = 
   (select s.salesman_id 
      from salesman s 
      where bid.salesman = s.display_name)
```